# Qt Creator: Could not start process ""

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

faced with an issue during qt creator using (re-build action):

> Running steps for project algolist...  Could not start process "" clean
>   Error while building/deploying project algolist (kit: MSVC2015)

Environment settings:

1. QtCreator 3.5.1
2. Windows 10 (and SDK forWin10)
3. visual c++ compiler with libraries version 19
4. I do not use any qt libraries in a project, and havew an installed qt kit just for qmake support (qmake is a build tool for my project)
5. all compiler's settings are manual via INCLUDE/LIB/PATH. and this configuration works on my other machine, can't find a differences and the message above doesn't look informative, could you someone explain me please what this mean ? 
   thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as fas as I use manual compiler configuration , I had to specify nmake path there as well. so this fix in compiler config fixed my problem
sorry for my inattention